# pd.read_csv(‘df’, chunksize=chunksize)

Tags: pandas

I have data on the sale and condition of cars and in the power column there are a lot of objects with an engine size < 50
I'm trying to replace these values with the average which I've aggregated across the brand and model columns
Due to the fact that df has more than 322 thousand objects, it does not fit in my ram memory and I have to use `pd.read_csv(‘df’, chunksize=chunksize)`

then I do everything in a loop and everything works fine until the 23rd iteration

and I have no explanation why everything worked with the same data types, but from 23 times refuses to work correctly

[fale_csv](https://code.s3.yandex.net/datasets/autos.csv)

```
# Set chunk size
chunksize = 10000

# Read data in chunks
reader = pd.read_csv('autos.csv', chunksize=chunksize)

# Initialize empty dataframe to store the results
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Brand', 'Model', 'Power'])
# Process each chunk separately

d = 0
for chunk in reader:
    # Calculate power mean for the current chunk
    power_mean = chunk.groupby(['Brand', 'Model'])['Power'].agg('mean').reset_index()
    # Filter out low-power vehicles for the current chunk
    low_power = chunk.loc[chunk['Power'] < 50]
    # Merge low_power and power_mean dataframes forb the current chunk
    merged_df = pd.merge(low_power, power_mean, on=['Brand', 'Model'], how='left')
    # Merge merged_df and the original dataframe for the current chunk
    merged_df = pd.merge(chunk[['Brand', 'Model', 'Power']], merged_df, on=['Brand', 'Model'], how='left')
    # Update power values in the original dataframe for the current chunk
    chunk.loc[merged_df['Power_y'].notnull(), 'Power'] = merged_df['Power_y']
    # Append the processed chunk to the result dataframe
    result = pd.concat([result, chunk])
    print(f'# {d}')
    print(merged_df['Power_y'].head(2))
    d+=1
```

I want to understand why it happens, how is it possible that part of the data works, but the other part of the same type and quality does not work
And how to solve this problem with `chunksize=chunksize`

---

[error view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EIDK.png)

I looked at the data types that I generate everything ok

just now I noticed that the type is
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

and I don't know why it's different from
`pd.DataFrame`?

No more ideas and it's been three days
I can't take it anymore, I'll go to sleep

Comment: Re your typing question: `pd.DataFrame == pd.core.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: NO                                           

`chunksize=chunksize` gives 36 parts from file_csv
the loop runs 23 times without error and stops working

Why?
The data in 23 working parts and in the remaining 13 parts are the same in my opinion

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.   Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks @itprorh66

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it became clear to me why the code that is fully working in the middle of the way broke

I can't speak with full confidence in the details, but this error is somehow related to the chunksize
by changing the chunksize from 10000 to 20000, the code worked as it should

It's still unclear why this is happening.
If you know the answer, please post!

These three days of searching for the error are of course invaluable in terms of experience.
I corrected the error, but I did not find the cause

***Solution code***

```
chunksize = 20000
```